# Override the ResourceManager in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, resourcemanager

Is it possible to override the ResourceManager in an ASP.NET MVC2 application?
I've skim read several articles about creating a resource provider, but this seems like overkill. All I want to do is override the GetResourceFileName(CultureInfo culture) method on ResourceManager.

many thanks,
Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently looked for solution , and implementing  based on fallowing [Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/) article. There is no official example of implementing custom ResourceManager.